# Trying to align images centrally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have 4 icons that align horizontally. However I would like to have them align with each other through a center line if that makes sense. At the moment they aren't matching up. The top of one image may be in line with the middle of another for example. The icons are of different sizes but I don't mind that, as long as the align centrally. Here is my html

```
<section class="feature">
    <div class="grid_4">
        <img src="images/image-1.png">
        <p>
            <a href="#">Email</a> 
            iamapdige@<br>hotmail.com               
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4">
        <img src="images/image-2.png">
        <p>
            <a href="#">Mobile</a><br> 
            Call or text 085PIDGEON             
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4">
        <img src="images/image-3.png">
        <p>
            <a href="#">Facebook</a><br>
            Check us out on Facebook!       
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4">
        <img src="images/image-4.png">
        <p>
            <a href="#">Twitter</a><br>
            Tweet me! @pidgeon          
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

And the relevant CSS

```
.feature { 
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.feature img { 
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;    
}
```

Thanks for any help. If it's not clear what I mean then I can upload a picture of the PS template to explain.

Comment: so i'm assuming you want it centered and horizontally aligned?

Answer (score 0):

If the icons are all different widths but you want them all centered on top of each other, try putting the images in spans.  Set the width of the spans to be the width of the widest icon, and use text-align:center on them.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VerdeletG/kubqvu30/)

Basically, you need to adjust the margins inside, and make the bordering container that i added equal to the sum of the widths and margins of the grid_4s.

so:

```
.feature{
  width:600px;
  margin:auto;
}
.grid_4{
  width:100px;
  margin:25px;
}
```

What the margin auto does is that is adjusts its margins automatically within section's width of 100%. the margins auto-position itself in the center based on the width of the container feature. therefore if you want your images central and aligned horizontally, then they need to perfectly equal the width of the feature div, so add up the width and margins (horizontally) and come with the answer as the width of feature, if you follow...

hope this helps!